# Ways to edit SharePoint Online list form

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, powerapps-forms

I want to know, if there is any way to edit the SharePoint online List form(Add/Edit) without using PowerApps as there are problem with respect to licenses.

My aim is hide the columns in form based on logged in user. I'm looking to achieve this without any cost involved, please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the modern experience list forms using Power Apps only.

However, you can show or hide columns in a list or form using conditional formula.

Check this documentation: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

---

**Additional**: You can customize the list forms using JSON formatting up to some extent. Check this documentation: [Configure the list form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Then I think, hiding columns based on logged in user permission can be achieved by Powerapps only

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you want to hide based on permissions, you have to use power apps.